# Why is Black Widow's last name "Romanoff" not "Romanova"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow

My understanding of Russian names is that for women, the names end in "-ova", and for men they end in "-ov" or "-off".

But Black Widow's last name if always listed as "Romanoff" - shouldn't it be "Romanova"? They might have gotten it wrong when the character was first created, but they would have fixed by 2008.

Is there a reason, or is this just poor design?

Comment: Looks like in some places it's listed as Romanova and other places Romanoff (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Widow_(Natasha_Romanova) My guess is this is going to be a case of "writers didn't know any better" when the character was created.

Comment: In that entry it also says: "She has sometimes chosen the last-name alias "Romanoff"—evidently as a private joke on those who are not aware that Russian family names use different endings for males and females." So I suppose, in universe, it is possible she uses Romanoff as an alias?

Comment: It's usually like that with gender-sensitive Russian last names when they are converted to English.  I'm not sure how it started, but it possibly had to do with married couples having a name that registers as a single name in Russian (spelled in two different ways due to gender), but as two different names in English.  Either way, to an English speaker the ending "ova" is an unusual one, since English defaults to giving the male Russian name to both men and women.  Stan Lee is not a Russian speaker - so I'd guess that, when he originally created Black Widow, he thought *Romanoff* was correct.

Comment: Simplest explanation is that when she was created the writers weren't hugely aware (or care) about Slavic naming conventions.

Comment: Interesting factoid.  I am not sure whether the Russian naming convention is based on Slavic or Greek customs or possibly both.  In the middle ages the Russian Orthodox church was dependent on the Patriarch of Constantinople.  After about 800 the noble families of the eastern Roman or "Byzantine" empire used family names, and each family name had a different form for males and females.

Comment: Does Natasha ever say her family name? English speakers in-universe who meet her are probably already familiar with the masculine form from history class, which could cause them to remember her name that way.

Comment: @Gaultheria *English speakers in-universe who meet her are probably already familiar with the masculine form history class* - Considering that even Russians often have a foggy knowledge of the Romanovs' history, I'd guess that most English speakers don't know who the Romanovs were. Nor is there any good reason why they should, other that specific interest in pre-revolution Russia. There is, however, a cheap gross *Romanoff* brand vodka. In sure plenty of college students mix it into their drinks once they've finished their history homework, so they may still be familiar with the name.

Comment: I guess I could have expanded that to "from history or noodles or strawberries or whatever". The masculine form of the name seems to be much more common than the feminine form in English where I live, so I thought it might predispose Natasha's colleagues to make assumptions and that she might not have corrected them.

Comment: As you say it is a last name, her name is Natasha, so maybe there is the diference. But in some places is called Romanova and in other places is called Romanoff, so maybe it case of the writers.

Answer (score 3):

Romanoff is the Anglicisation of the Russian surname Romanov/Romanova.
Because of Anglicisation, the gender attached to the surname is lost in translation.

Now because she defects to the west, it is an accurate change in the surname.

The same has happened with the Romanoff Family Association, they anglicanized because of what little survived (distant relatives from Nicholas II & Feodorovna) were basically exiled out of Russia.

Living members are in UK, Greece, France, and the United States.

Comment: This feels like pure guesswork. Can you offer any evidence that this is what the writers intended?